# Do turbo prop airliners generate thrust using the propeller and compressed air or just the propeller?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I looked at a picture of a q400 engine and it showed air being compressed so I was wondering if it has two systems to generate thrust.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turboprop engines transfer almost all of the turbine's rotational energy to the propeller, though there is some waste in heat and exhaust gas as in all engines. The exhaust does not form any major amount of thrust unlike in other turbine engines ("jet engines", like a turbofan or turbojet). Turboprops are more efficient than other "jet engines" at lower altitudes due to the thickness of the air at lower altitudes whereas jets are more efficient at higher altitudes, though turboprop pilots will tell you they fly a jet, being that a turboprop is still a turbine engine, aka a jet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The PT6A provides approximately 10% extra thrust from exhaust gas

http://www.turbokart.com/about_pt6.htm

Comment: Where does the linked article say so? I can't find it. Also many aircraft employing PT6A have the exhausts mounted so that they only loosely direct the exhaust gas to the rear (PT6A is a reverse flow engine; the gasses exit the engine itself _forward_) and nothing like a nozzle that could generate thrust.